# Ruin time with a maximum purse size

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Imagine I have a gambler's ruin scenario where I start with $m$ dollars and I cannot have more than $N$ dollars.  For each of however many rounds, I flip a coin, and with probability $p$ I win a dollar, and with probability $(1-p)$ I lose a dollar.  If I win a dollar when I already have $m=N$ dollars, I simply do not lose a dollar.

What is my ruin time (i.e. the time to reach $m=0$)?  Can we calculate a variance for the ruin time?

I'm sure this must be a classic result, but I cannot find the example in books such as (Parzen 1962), or Feller...

Comment: This is an example of a standard problem for Markov Chains. Both the variance and the average ruin time can be found as solutions of certain linear equations. For the average time check out [the first chapter of the book "Markov Chain" by Norris](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s13.pdf). When you're done with it, you can easily derive the equation for the second moment.